# PHP: Array undefined?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p>
        <?php
          
            $SupportNinga = array("Email1@gmail.com", "Email2@yahoo.com");
            echo $SupportNinga;

            $num = rand(1, count($SupportNinja));
            $SupportNinja = $SupportNinja[$num];
            echo $SupportNinja;

        ?>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code seems to not define the variable, for it gives error:

> Array
>
> Undefined variable: SupportNinja (line 11)Undefined variable: SupportNinja (line 12)

Comment: Arrays are indexed from __0__, not from __1__: `$num= rand(0,count($SupportNinja) - 1);`

Comment: Check the names of your arrays.. You are trying to use `$SupportNinja` before you have declared it.

Comment: And `$SupportNinga` !== `$SupportNinja`

Comment: oh. Darn it, i have a friend named ningamew. .-. I keep forgetting -_-

Comment: use print_r($SupportNinga) onstead of echo $SupportNinga;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable SupportNinja is not defined because you use array name $SupportNinga not $SupportNinja

```
$SupportNinga = array("Email1@gmail.com","Email2@yahoo.com");
```

change variable name **$SupportNinga** to **SupportNinja**

```
$SupportNinja = array("Email1@gmail.com","Email2@yahoo.com");
```

> NOTE::-  echo $SupportNinga doesn't print array key value pair.it's print "Array" so use `print_r($SupportNinga);` instead of `echo $SupportNinga;`

Answer (score 1):

Change `$SupportNinga` to `$SupportNinja`.

Also you cannot echo a array. Use `print_r()` to display array on line 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num= rand(1,count($SupportNinja));
```

This line gets you a random integer between 1 and 2 (the item count in the array).

in php array indices start beginning from 0. Thus you should write instead :

```
$num= rand(1,count($SupportNinja))-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name of array as `$SupportNinja` instead of `$SupportNinga`.

Also use `print_r()` or `var_dump` for printing content inside of any array like :

```
print_r($SupportNinja); \\ printing content inside array $SupportNinja
```

and moreover `echo` is used for printing strings not array.